# Deserialize inline elementlist directly into a List

Tags: java, xml, xml-serialization, simple-framework

I have the following XML structure:

```
<keys>
   <key>
      <tag>
         someValue
      </tag>
   </key>
   <key>
      <tag>
         someValue
      </tag>
   </key>
</keys>
```

The `key` element is represented in code in the following class:

```
public class Key {

    @Element(name = "tag")
    private String tag;
}
```

My goal is to deserialize these directly into a `List`, something like this:

```
Serializer serializer = new Persister();
List<Key> list = serializer.read(Key.class, inputStream); // pseudo code
```

How can i achieve this with [Simple](http://simple.sourceforge.net/)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the @ElementList annotation like so

```
@Root(name="keys")
public class KeyList {

    @ElementList(inline=true, entry="key")
    private List<Key> keys;

    public List<Key> getKeys() {
       return keys;
    }
}
```

Then

```
Persister persister = new Persister();
List<Key> keys = persister.read(KeyList.class, source).getKeys();
```

Comment: Thanks! It works well. I guess there is no way to skip this helper `KeyList` class, am i right?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using JAXB (Java Architecture for XML Binding)

Here's a link to a couple of tutorials:

- http://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/
- [opentutorials: jaxb into a list](http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/java/jaxb/jaxb-marshalling-and-unmarshalling-list-of-objects/)

They can explain it better than me. 
But basically you use annotations defined in the javax.xml.bind.annotation package which define your xml structure.
Then create a simple JAXB Handler class to handle marshaling and unmarshaling.

Comment: Thanks! If it was not clear: we use the [Simple framework](http://simple.sourceforge.net/), and we do not want to change to another,